# jquery not changing class to invisible on click function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a section of my webpage that will either display the company's stock quote, a historical chart or the latest press releases. The aspx mark up is show below with some removed for brevity.

```
<div id="StockQuote" class="invisible">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updplStockQuote" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>                  
                <span class="stockpricefont"><i>Last Sale:</i><b id="lastsale" runat="server"></b></span>
                     &nbsp;<asp:Image ID="imgNetChangeArrow" runat="server" /><span class="otherstockinfofont"><b id="netchange" runat="server"></b></span>
                            <span class="stockpricefont"><i>Market Cap:</i></span><span class="otherstockinfofont"><b id="marketcap" runat="server"></b></span><br />
                <span class="otherstockinfofont2"><i>Net Change(%):</i>&nbsp;<asp:Image ID="imgNetChgPctArrow" runat="server" /> <b id="netchangepct" runat="server"> </b></span><br />
                <span class="otherstockinfofont2"><i>Open:</i><b id="priceopen" runat="server"></b></span><br />
                <span class="otherstockinfofont2"><i>High:</i><b id="pricehigh" runat="server"></b></span><br />
                <span class="otherstockinfofont2"><i>Low:</i><b id="pricelow" runat="server"></b></span><br />
                <span class="otherstockinfofont2"><i>Volume:</i><b id="pricevolume" runat="server"></b></span><br />
                <span class="otherstockinfofont2"><i>Prior Close:</i><b id="pricepriorclose" runat="server"></b></span><br />


            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
               <%-- <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger/>--%>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    <div id="StockChart" class="visible">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlStockChart" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <%-- All the asp chart code is here--%>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlChartTimeFrame" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

Here is the script

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        function aTagClick(event) {
            if ($(this).text() === "Stock Quote") {
                if ($('#StockQuote').hasClass('invisible')) {
                    $('#StockChart').toggleClass('invisible');
                    $('#StockQuote').toggleClass('visible');           

                } 
            } else if ($(this).text() === "Stock Chart") {
                if ($('#StockChart').hasClass('invisible')) {
                    $('#StockChart').toggleClass('visible');
                    $('#StockQuote').toggleClass('invisible');
                }
            }}           
        $('#a_stockqoute').click(aTagClick);
        $('#a_stockchart').click(aTagClick);
        $('#a_latestnews').click(aTagClick);
    });
```

Here is the CSS

.invisible
{
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
}

The page opens with the chart visible. If I click on the stock quote tag, the quote displays but the chart div does not become invisible as it should. What am I missing? Clicking on the stock Chart tag will now make the chart disappear. I am somewhat new to jquery but cannot figure out why this is behaving this way

Working script

```
 function aTagClick(event) {
            if ($(this).text() === "Stock Quote") {
                if ($('#StockQuote').css('display') == 'none') {
                    $('#StockChart').hide();
                    $('#StockQuote').show();
                }
            } else if ($(this).text() === "Stock Chart") {
                if ($('#StockChart').css('display') == 'none') {
                    $('#StockChart').show();
                    $('#StockQuote').hide();
                }
            }}
```

Comment: "invisible" is just a class name... be more specific

Comment: Where is the CSS for "visible" and "invisible"?

Comment: I would only use one toggleClass and set it too display:none elements by default will display either inline or block

Comment: I edited the post to include the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this:

```
if ($('#StockQuote').hasClass('invisible')) {
    $('#StockChart').toggleClass('invisible');
    $('#StockQuote').toggleClass('visible');
}
```

I feel like I'd prefer it to look like:

```
if ($('#StockQuote').css('display')=='none') {
    $('#StockChart').hide();
    $('#StockQuote').show();
}
```

I'd need to see a JSFiddle to be sure, though.

//Chase.

### Edit in response to the very sweet Mangotastic

I think the entire JavaScript code here can be shortened to:

```
$(function () {        
    $('#a_stockquote,a_stockchart').click(function(){ 
        $('#StockQuote,#StockChart').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

***NOTE: I fixed the spelling of `#a_stockqoute` to `#a_stockquote`.***

Again, I'd need a JSFiddle to be sure.

***//Chase.***

Comment: If StockChart and StockQuote load with one hidden and one shown then just calling `.toggle()` on both should do the same, right?

Comment: Actually.. yeah. It would be the same.

Comment: You know, @Mangotastic, friend, I believe you're right. I made an edit to my answer that includes a much more optimized way of going about the asker's task. Thanks Mango :) //Chase.